# Редактирование html текста в БД по шаблону через запрос SQL

Tags: sql

Возможно ли такое реализовать через интерфейс phpMyAdmin? К примеру обернуть все слова "Описание" в таблице product_description в тег

```html
<h2></h2>
```

?

Comment: Возможно. Сделайте SQL запрос и выполните его.

Comment: Можно написать пример такого запроса? С sql только начинаю знакомиться.

Comment: phpmyadmin тут вообще не причем, это лишь средство работы с БД. В mysql вы можете заменить слово на что то другое (например на него же в тегах) с помощью обычного update, воспользовавшись в нем функцией replace https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

Answer (score 1):

Обернуть все поле

```
UPDATE `product_description` SET `description` = CONTACT('<h2>', `description`, '</h2>');
```

Либо одно слово

```
UPDATE `product_description` SET `description` = REPLACE(`description`, 'Описание', '<h2>Описание</h2>');
```

Comment: Благодарю......